# Why is there some ambiguity in the way sizeof() function works in C++, when using struct

Tags: c++

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}

cout<<sizeof(struct node)<<sizeof(node)<<endl; 
//no error, C++ allows us to use sizeof(struct node) and sizeof(node) both.
```

Whereas we cannot do the same with int datatype

```
int a;
cout<<sizeof(int) <<sizeof(a) <<endl;//there is no error here

  //BUT

cout<<sizeof(int a) <<endl;//this throws an error
```

I understand that "struct node" itself is like a datatype which can be used to declare variable of type "struct node". Going by the behavior of how sizeof() works with int, it is understandable that sizeof(struct node) is equivalent to sizeof(datatype) and hence is correct usage.

But how does sizeof(node) work as well ? It does not throw any error. "node" in itself cannot be used to declare any other variables, it needs to be "struct node" to declare a variable.

Comment: You are not doing the same thing.

Comment: How does sizeof(node) work ? Shouldn't it error. Just node as such is not really useful unless I use some typedef, which I haven't.

Comment: @Qrious Try `sizeof(struct node node_instance)`. That's more simmilar to what you're doing with `int`.

Comment: <<it needs to be "struct node" to declare a variable>>: says who? https://ideone.com/Z0Z0dC

Comment: @LogicStuff Yes, I get your point. But my question is mainly to understand how sizeof(node) works without any error. "node" alone has no significance right ? I have not declared any variable of type node. If I had declared a variable of type node using struct node node1 and used sizeof(node1), I understand that this is correct usage. But just using sizeof(node) should have errored.

Comment: @Rene now I see why sizeof(node) works just fine.. Thanks !

Comment: @Rene, if we do not need to use struct node to declare a variable and using just "node" works fine while declaring a variable, then what is the use of typedef ? Example: 
struct node {
int a;
struct node *next;
};

struct node node1;
node node2;
//Both these above declarations work fine. That means we do not need typedef while declaring struct variables ?

Comment: @Qrious Right, in C++ you don't need the typedef: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Answer (score 5):

In C++, a class type declared as `struct A {/* blah blah blah */};` or `class A {/* blah blah blah*/};` can be referred to as a type later as `class A` or `struct A` or simply `A`. These types can be passed into the `sizeof` operator.

Variables can also be passed into the `sizeof` operator, like so:

```
int a;
long b;
node c;

std::cout << sizeof(a) << ' ' << sizeof(b) << ' ' << sizeof(node) << '\n';
```

But a variable declaration like `int a` cannot be put into the `sizeof` operator:

```
std::cout << sizeof(int a); // Compile error
```

Similarly, a declaration involving a class type cannot be put into the `sizeof` operator:

```
std::cout << sizeof(node c); // Compile error
```

Comment: Understood, thank you ! Thanks to @Rene also for pointing it out

Comment: "In C++, a class type declared as `struct A` or `class A`" +100 right there. Congratulations for spreading the correct notion that `struct` declares a class type in C++.